# How to override the move left motion

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I would like to map <kbd>H</kbd> to execute a function, which does the following:

- **If cursor on first column:** Wrap around/Move cursor to end of the current line
- **If cursor before/on first non-whitespace character of line:** Move cursor to first column
- **If cursor after first non-whitespace character of line:**

  - **If cursor less then five columns to the right of the first non-whitespace character of line:** Move cursor to first non-whitespace character of line.
  - **Otherwise:** Move cursor five columns to the left.

Sadly I never wrote a single function in vimscript and have no idea how to translate this idea into real code. Does anyone have an idea where I should look into to learn how to create this function?

Comment: [These functions I wrote](https://github.com/statox/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc#L365-L394) could give you some inspiration. The `H` one makes h go to the beginning of the line when the cursor is on the first non white character and go one character to the left if the cursor is anywhere else.

Comment: @statox Thank you! I'll definitely take a look :)

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7514/is-there-a-better-way-to-create-this-semi-strong-left-motion/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to add this to your `.vimrc` I didn't tested it extensively but it looks like it is working.

```
function! MyHMotion()
    " Get the position of the cursor and of the first non white character
    let cursorPosition=getpos(".")
    normal! ^
    let firstChar=getpos(".")

    if cursorPosition[2] == 1
        " Cursor on first column : go to the end of line
        normal! $
    elseif cursorPosition[2] <= firstChar[2]
        " Cursor before/on first non-whitespace character: go to first column
        normal! 0    
    elseif cursorPosition[2] <= firstChar[2]+5
        " cursor less than five columns after the first non-whitespace character: go to first non-white character
        normal! ^
    else
        " Move normally
        call setpos('.', cursorPosition)
        normal! h
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> h :call MyHMotion()<CR>
```

The function is commented and its behavior should be pretty clear. Here are some additional information:

- The `!` following `normal` is here so that the command will not use user-defined mappings. More info at `:h normal`
- The last line `nnoremap <silent> h :call MyHMotion()<CR>` is here to map <kbd>h</kbd> so that the function `MyHMotion()` is called each time you press the key.
- The `<silent>` argument is here so that nothing is echoed on the command line when the function is called. See `:h :map-silent`

I used [these functions of mine](https://github.com/statox/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc#L365-L394) as inspiration. They override <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> to skip the whitespaces at the beginning of a line:

```
" make h and l skip indentation white spaces {{{
    function! MyLMotion()
        let cursorPosition=getpos(".")
        normal! ^
        let firstChar=getpos(".")

        if cursorPosition[2] < firstChar[2]
            normal! ^
        else
            call setpos('.', cursorPosition)
            normal! l
        endif
    endfunction

    function! MyHMotion()
        let cursorPosition=getpos(".")
        normal! ^
        let firstChar=getpos(".")

        if cursorPosition[2] <= firstChar[2]
            normal! 0
        else
            call setpos('.', cursorPosition)
            normal! h
        endif
    endfunction

    nnoremap <silent> h :call MyHMotion()<CR>
    nnoremap <silent> l :call MyLMotion()<CR>
"}}}
```

Comment: Thank you really much. Your code makes sense to me. I'll play around with it a bit and accept the answer later :)

Comment: @Herickson you're welcome, if you encounter a problem don't hesitate to let me know I'll see how to fix it.

Comment: I'm currently wondering, what the exclamation mark after the `normal` means. Sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not.

Comment: It should be always there (I'll correct that) it makes `normal` use the default action of the key. For example if you had used `nnoremap 0 :echo "foo"<CR>` using `normal 0 ` would output "foo" as your mapping defined it but using `normal! 0 ` would go to the beginning of the line no matter what mapping you created.

Comment: Am I missing something, or should the first action be `normal! k$`?

Comment: @Tumbler41 It depends on what you want to do: OP said `Wrap around/Move cursor to end of line` I understand that as `wrap around the line, thus go to the end of the current line` but if you want to go to the end of the previous line it could be `k$`. Maybe I didn't understand what OP wanted.

Comment: Ok, I understood "Wrap around" to be go to the end of the previous line.

Comment: @Tumbler41 Sorry, for the misleading text. I actually intended to move the cursor to the end of the same line. I'll fix the question as soon as I'm not on mobile anymore.

Comment: @statox If you are interested: I modified your function a little bit and [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142188/vertical-movement-for-vim-vimscript) is what I came up with :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Herickson: Nice transformation! Just so you know our site [is open](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/1337/1841) to vimscript code reviews under the right circumstances. For your question on the CR site I won't make an answer because I don't have much to say, your code seems good :-)